# Unable to verify custom .ninja domain for Azure website

Tags: azure, dns, azure-web-app-service, verify

I'm trying to verify a custom `.ninja` domain for a Azure hosted website, but it fails to complete verification. I've completed these steps for several other sites and domains hosted in Azure before and familiar with the `awverify CNAME` requirement. I've also updated the A record(s) with the Azure provided IP. A `ping` on the domain name returns the correct IP. It has been close to 48 hours of waiting giving plenty of time for DNS settings to propagate.

Here's the error (I replaced the actual domain with "mydomain"):

> A CNAME record pointing from mydomain.ninja to mydomain.azurewebsites.net was not found. Alternative record awverify.mydomain.ninja to awverify.mydomain.azurewebsites.net was not found either.

Are there any restrictions on `.ninja` domains or those that do not have 3 char extensions maybe? All my other successful attempts with other sites have been on .com domains.

Comment: Somehow I was able to get this working.  The ONLY thing I changed was added an A Record with a www prefix.  Once this was added, verification for both the www and mydomain.ninja worked.  Go figure!

Answer (score 1):

Added an A record for the www prefix, thus having 2 A records.  One for @ and one for www.  Once the www record was added to DNS, verification worked for both www.mydomain.ninja and mydomain.ninja.  Odd, but maybe this will help someone else.